# How to write BeautifulSoup resultset to the html file?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am fetching amazon interview from the site http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-3/. I was able to get the resultset I desired but it is in the html form. This is how it looks:

```
<p> Hello People <p>
....
....
....
```

I want to output the html to a new html file and then use pdfkit to convert the html file to pdf.

As suggested in the answers I have installed wkhtmltopdf using the command pip install wkhtmltopdf.

And after that when I try to use the command

```
pdfkit.from_url('http://example.com/', 'sample.pdf')
```

OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

I googled the solution and followed the following steps:

1. Installed wkhtmltopdf using the windows installer.
2. Add the path of executable in the environment variable path for both system and the user.
3. Uninstalled wkhtmltopdf using pip command and then installed it back.

But the error remains the same.

Also when I import wkhtmltopdf module using the following command

```
import wkhtmltopdf
```

I get the error as follows

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\__init__.py in <module>()
1 from main import WKhtmlToPdf, wkhtmltopdf
  2 import api
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `pdfkit`, you can pipe the HTML string to it *directly*:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_string('your HTML string', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert .html file into .pdf format, this will do it on a fly.

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_file('sample.html', 'sample.pdf')
```

If you want to do via a url, do this instead.

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://sample.com', 'sample.pdf')
```

Comment: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: have you installed wkhtmltopdf??

Comment: First install wkhtmltopdf, then run 'pip install pdfkit'.

Comment: I have installed wkhtmltopdf but when I import it I get the error C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from main import WKhtmlToPdf, wkhtmltopdf
      2 import api

ImportError: No module named 'main'

Comment: pls upate your question adding the error, coz your question is not about the error only the way to do. :)) Pls add details, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error:

> No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''" If this file exists please
> check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install
> wkhtmltopdf -
> github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

The solution is to create a variable named "config" and pass the path for '\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' like:

```
config = pdf.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes('C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe', 'utf-8'))
```

Then do this:

```
pdf.from_file(file_html, 'sample.pdf', options=options, configuration=config)
```

Don't need to import wkhtmltopdf in your script. Just pass to config variable and it's done.